# Can't boot back to windows please help me

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu from a live USB but now it boots straight to Ubuntu and I can't seem to get back to windows. This is a report I got from Boot-Repair.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RTWDwP7hnZ/

Comment: There is no more Windows, it won't boot.

Comment: The paste.ubuntu.com works for me.

Comment: @K7AAY after the edit it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your paste, there is only one disk, and the entire disk is used by a single partition formatted with the ext4 filesystem, with Ubuntu installed. Sorry, but I don't think you will be able to get Windows back without re-installing it.

Comment: Yeah,i actually erased everything,so stupid of me.I also lost my windows 8 key :( .Is there any way to completely remove ubuntu and install windows 10?I think i can use windows 10 without a license right?

Comment: The Windows installer can be used to remove the Ubuntu partition, so that Windows can be re-installed.

Comment: I don't have access to windows though?

Comment: You''ll have to create a new Windows 10 installation USB stick. It can be done rather easily from Windows, or from linux but it is a little more complex:

* From Windows: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support

* From Linux: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu

Windows 10 can be installed without a key and activated later.

Sorry for the edits, enter causes the comment to save unexpectedly. I'm new here too.